# On characterizations of $p$-integral operators

Tags: banach-spaces

In most of papers and classical text books, $p$-integral operators are defined and characterized by operators and commutative diagrams. This is quite different from $p$-summing operators and $p$-nuclear operators. I am wondering whether there are characterizations of $p$-integral operators by sequences such as weakly $p$-summable sequences, $p$-summable sequences.

Comment: I have not seen such a characterization and cannot imagine what could be one.

Comment: This question may be stupid. It is well-known that on $l_{\infty}^{*}$, $weak^{*}$ convergent sequences are weakly convergent. Are there other spaces having this nice property besides $l_{\infty}$? Or what's the name of this property?

Comment: A space having that property is called  a Grothendieck space.  Reflexive spaces and injective spaces and combinations thereof are the standard examples. I don't think that there is any characterization of this class of spaces.